# Normal font in equations quoted with Dollar

Tags: fonts, equations

Text or formula within ${---}$ and in itemize are in italic.
How to convert into normal??
I have used `\text` and `\mathrm` but it's not working.
Anyone please find solution for this following code:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item {\ Y(t)\  =\ A\ Sin($2\pi f_{in}t)$} \newline
$\implies{Slope, s\ =\ \frac{dy}{dt}\ = 2\pi f_{in}Acos(2\pi f_{in}t)]}$
\item{$Suppose \ n=10\ bits\ and\ t_{s}=1ns$}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome @chaisrav, please provide a minimum working example. (This means, include all the stuff before `\begin{document}`, so that we have a better idea exactly what's going on with your code.)

Answer (score 2):

I think that `\text` is an `amsmath` command.

Try adding `\usepackage{amsmath}` to your preamble (before `\begin{document}`, then try using `\text{}` again.

Also note that for functions like `cos`, you really want to be them to be operators. For common functions, you can achieve this just by using `\cos` instead. This will put `cos` in upright text, and as a bonus, adjust the spacing.

Also, you shouldn't be using `\` (backslash space) inside maths mode. Spacing should be automatic. (Maths mode does destroy spaces, but this is usually a good thing.)

Alternatively, just don't use `$$` when you want text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $Y(t) = A \sin(2\pi f_{in}t)$ \\
    $\implies$ Slope, $s = \frac{dy}{dt} = 2\pi f_{in}A \cos(2\pi f_{in}t)$
\item Suppose $n=10$ bits and $t_{s}=1ns$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I very strongly recommend [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX 2ε](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf).
Save it to your computer! I still reference this document regularly.